# Modifying native module to work with other tables

Tags: joomla, module, joomla2.5

I want to modify a native joomla module that display articles of a category. I want it to display articles of an other prefix tables (both joomla website are on the same server).

Notice that I already looked at available extension but none of them would fit.

I tried to modify the helper.php of the native joomla module 
tables, by changing the

`$com_path =`
but i am getting a`Fatal error.`

Native code:
`$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';`

My try :
`$com_path = '/homez.420/kmxsiksf/rsc/components/com_content/helpers/route.php`

Comment: so are you trying to connect to route.php or need the code to retrieve articles for Joomla 2.5?

Comment: Hi lodder, well actually i was trying to modify the helper.php of the native modul, I thought the path could be change inside it, am I wrong?. I never heard about route.php does it communicate with helper.php and set the path? Thanks for your reply, I really need some info about the global way to do it

Comment: yes, you will need to use `require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/router.php';`. If you would like me to send you the `helper.php` I used for my accordion to retrieve Joomla 2.5 articles then I would be more than happy to do so.

Comment: Actually my post title is not clear enough : modifying .... to work with -external- tables (other prefix)

Comment: Ho Lodder you are so great ! Should I post the helper.php here?

Comment: Here is the beginning only as it's a very long!

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';
require_once $com_path.'router.php';
require_once $com_path.'helpers/route.php';

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path . '/models', 'ContentModel');

Comment: abstract class modArticlesCategoryHelper
{public static function getList(&$params)
 {
  // Get an instance of the generic articles model
  $articles = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

  // Set application parameters in model
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $appParams = $app->getParams();
  $articles->setState('params', $appParams);

  // Set the filters based on the module params
  $articles->setState('list.start', 0);
  $articles->setState('list.limit', (int) $params->get('count', 0));
  $articles->setState('filter.published', 1);

Comment: you would be better off posting it as an answer with code tags if the problem has been solved ;)

Comment: Actually we are 2 very excited people trying to answer ...(one in Canada one in Germany...)  Answer is too short also we are trying to find a way to send you the file...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14015/joomla-chat

Comment: I uploaded the 2 files a this address: http://ge.tt/9RiVSdK : the helper.php and also the mod_articles_category.php. I believe the route is set in the helper.php but I am not to sure though. Thanks for your help Lodder! (I am the Canadian friend, because Giom is on his phone so it's not very practical for him!) We have been looking for an answer since days, but couldn't find the trick!

Comment: feel free to download my accordion module which uses the code to retrieve Joomla 2.5 articles: http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/module-home/accordion.html#download

Comment: Lodder does you accordeon module retrieve articles from external tables (other prefix) and if yes, did you copy and modified a second router.php?

Comment: no, not from external tables however you can adapt the database connection code to connect to a specific table manually. And no, I didn't copy and modify the route.php, I just connected to the default Joomla one.

Comment: I would worship you for the rest of my life if you explain me how to do it manually! I can start a new subject so I could vote for your answer.

Comment: `$connection = mysql_connect('HOST', 'DB_USER' , 'PASSWORD');`
`$selection = mysql_select_db('DB_NAME', $connection);`  Then simply use the `SELECT FROM` sql query

Comment: Thanks! But should I insert that in the helper.php I sent you?

Comment: well are the articles coming from the Joomla database or a completely separate database? if they are coming from a completely separate database, the yes, add the code I sent you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lodder! The articles are on the same databse but on different table : my website is using the arcs_ table and the article I want to use ar on the rsc_ table.

Comment: ahh I see now, in that case try changing `FROM #__tablename` to 
`FROM rsc_table`

Comment: Great thanks for your help Lodder! I did a search and I can only find the #__tablename in the router.php. So I will change it there. Should I also change the com_path in the helper.php and set it to something like : $com_path ='/homez.420/kmxsiksf/rsc/components/com_content/helpers/route.php`?

Comment: the table name shouldnt be defined in `route.php`, it should be in `helper.php`. And no, dont change `$com_path` to that, leave it as `require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/router.php';`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience Lodder! I haven't explain very well and you understood it! I did a search in the helper.php and there is nothing like #_content.

Comment: I did also have a look into your accordion module helper.php and I can't find any #_content. Do you know where this #_content is hidden?

Comment: Thanks so much Lodder! Here is one solution! Great! As I çan only use the accordion (for a FAQ) only if I can use the native joomla module, I wonder where should I change this #_content as it's not in its helper.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an external database (even if it's on your server) in Joomla extensions, the proper way would be to set some options before retrieving the JDatabase-object.

Create a helperclass to handle your external db, and in every method that uses the DB-object you simply set the options of your external db before retrieving the object:

```
$option = array(); 
$option['driver']   = 'mysql';
$option['host']     = 'localhost';    // In your case probably localhost 
$option['user']     = 'dbusername';       // User for database authentication $option['password'] = 'badpass12345';   // Password for database authentication $option['database'] = 'bigdatabase';      // Database name 
$option['prefix']   = 'abc_';             // Database prefix (may be empty)  
$db = & JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
```

You are now able to use your external database the same way as you would with your regular db.